# How do I install PHP 5.4.9 with Homebrew on my Mac?

Tags: php, homebrew

I need to upgrade the PHP on my Mac from 5.3.x to 5.4.9, which is the version that's on our server.  How do I do that with Homebrew?  I tried `brew install php54` and got an error that it didn't know that formula.  Where can I get a list of formulas so I know what my options are?  I tried `brew list` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php - here is instruction step by step how install php 5.4.9

Comment: Perhaps this would be better on serverfault?