# pg_connect undefined function on osx mavericks

Tags: php, macos, postgresql

I have looked at multiple SO threads and none of them seem to have my problem. I have compiled and install the pro_pgsql extension as outlined here: http://blog.rupey.org/post/63221360055/adding-postgres-support-to-php-on-os-x-mavericks and verified that it is loaded by running `php -m` apache has been restarted, php_info shows the following:
[image]

But when I run this script:

```
echo "hi!";
$ebdb_conn = pg_connect('dbname=mydb user=frank password=frank123') or die(pg_last_error());
```

I get the following error in the log:

```
[Mon Jun 09 12:39:05 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_connect() in /Users/frank/Code/ebus/test.php on line 4
```

This is on OSX Mavericks, with Apache and PHP 5.2.24. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was eventually solved by uninstalling everything that had to do with the Enterprise DB postgres package and reinstalling it with a consistent set of packages. I still, unfortunately have a non-matching psql client on the machine but other than that it is working fine. For others seeing this, I recommend:

DO NOT use enterprise DB installer found on the postgres website on OSX Mavericks use one of the following

1) postgres app (http://postgresapp.com) nice because its has postGIS and other extensions built in

2) map ports packages (https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/databases/postgresql82/Portfile)

3) brew installer (http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/)

Answer (score -1):

pg_connect isn't a part of the PDO library.  It's contained in the direct postgresql library for PHP.  In MacPorts, that's php5-postgresql, which macports gets from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/php5-postgresql.

Comment: I installed macports and `sudo port install php5-postgresql` followed by `sudo apachectl restart` same error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like you're using two different sets of installation instructions to get to the same goal.  From the OP, I assumed you were installing everything from source, and needed the code lib for pg_connect.   If you just want to know the easiest way to install PHP and PostgreSQL on Mavericks, that's a different question.

Comment: Homebrew instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805457/how-do-i-install-php-5-4-9-with-homebrew-on-my-mac

Comment: Installation instructions for MacPorts here: http://www.macports.org/install.php Then you install php and postgresql with: sudo port install php5-postgresql.

Comment: I originally installed postgres from EnterpriseDB (i.e. the link on the postgres site) but have uninstalled and reinstalled with mac ports packages `postgresql93-server` and `php54-postgresql` and still have the same error.Anything I am missing?

Comment: are you using the built-in apache2 from OSX or the one from macports?  

   sudo port install php54-apache2handler
   sudo port load apache2

Comment: The link in your answer is dead (perhaps you could update it?) I'm having the same problem and don't really understand your answer. If I do brew install php5-postgresql it says No available formula for it, and I can't seem to find it anywhere. I previously successfully did brew install php56 --with-apache --with-pgsql=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/ Any help appreciated!